# What is the meaning/usefulness of this exchange in Seinfeld's The Limo?

Tags: seinfeld

At the outset of the Season 3 Seinfeld episode, "The Limo", Jerry and George are stranded at the airport.  George sees a limousine driver holding a sign that says "O'Brien."  He talks Jerry into posing as O'Brien and Murphy to get a free ride.

As they go to approach the limo driver, a traveler asks Jerry and George if they know the time.  George tells the traveler dismissively, "There's a clock on the wall.", and pulls Jerry away.

This interaction doesn't seem to add to the scene.  By now in the series, George's character is well-developed as a misanthrope.  It does ring true to Larry David's aesthetic of unwarranted advances by strangers in public.

Ultimately I am wondering if I am missing something with this scene.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The scene is in reference to something else that happened shortly before that in the episode. George had asked a different stranger the time and the stranger refused to tell him; instead telling him to look at the clock on the wall. From [the script](https://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheLimo.html).

> George: Excuse me, sir, do you have the time?
>
> Man: There's a clock over there.
>
> George: Where?
>
> Man (pointing): There.
>
> George: But you have a watch on.
>
> Man: It's right by the escalator.
>
> George: Why don't you just look at your watch?
>
> Man: I told you, it's right over there.
>
> George: Let me see the watch.
>
> George grabs the man's wrist.
>
> Man: Hey! What are you, some kind of nut?!
>
> George: You know we're living in a society!

[...]

> [Different] Man (to George): Hey, do you have the time?
>
> George: Clock over there. (to chauffer) O'Brien.

So the joke here is George's hypocrisy. He was upset that a stranger wouldn't give him the time; and instead dismissively told him to look at the clock. His complaint was that as members of a society, people should be polite and helpful towards one another. But then, just minutes later, he shows that he is part of the very problem he complained about; that he would rather tell a stranger to look at the clock than to tell him the time.

Comment: The joke's glaring flaw is that George wasn't wearing a working watch or he wouldn't have asked the original passerby for the time in the first place. He might have guessed at the current time but he didn't have a watch for confirmation.

Comment: @Jeeped I've thought that same thing when watching the scene, but I think a more polite person would have said "sorry, I don't have a watch".. which ironically is more polite but less helpful than "clock over there". So to be polite and helpful, you have to go with "sorry, I don't have a watch,but there's a clock on the wall over there".

Comment: @Jeeped Since only a short while has passed since George found out the time, he basically still knows the approximate time and could easily have told the other person.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman - I did mention that *'He might have guessed at the current time'...* but airport time (arrivals and departures) runs on minutes if not seconds. If the passer-by needed to  find his departure gate in *x* number of minutes then an exact time was of essence. If locating an arrival time to find a passenger then maybe not so much. In any event, I've forgotten how long it was between the two situations.

Comment: I thought the joke was that he said 'we live in a society' in the earlier scene

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe Yes, I think that is in line with the interpretation in my answer.